# Function Template: typename declaration

Tags: c++, templates

On GCC, The following gives me an error: `no type named 'x' in 'struct Type'`

On VC++, It complains about `p` being undeclared

```
struct Type
{
   static int const x = 0;
};

template <class T> void Func()
{
   typename T::x * p; // p to be pointer
}

int main()
{
   Func<Type>();
}
```

Comment: So? Invalid code can easily result in completely different diagnostic messages issued by different compilers. Your code is invalid. As long as the compiler issues a diagnostic message in response to your code, that compiler is OK. What is your question, BTW?

Comment: My question was about using the variable `x` as typename to declare a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T::x` becomes `Type::x`, which is an `int`, not a type.

You've told the compiler that `T::x` names a type by using `typename`.  When `Func<Type>` is instantiated, `T::x` is not a type, so the compiler reports an error.

Comment: I see, I guess I would need a nested class inside Type to encapsulate integer x.

Comment: Well, that depends on what, exactly, you are trying to do :-/

Comment: I was only thinking about using the keyword 'typename' in front but confused the built-in types with class types. thanks.

Comment: @user31231: "confused the built-in types with class types" No. You confused types and objects. There is no much difference between built-in types and classes. But the name of the _object_ cannot be used instead of type name.

Answer (score 0):

Since `Type::x` is not a *type*, rather a *value*, so when you write `typename`, you're telling the compiler to find a nested *type* with name `x` inside `Type`, but it couldn't. Hence the GCC says `no type named 'x' in 'struct Type'` which is more  helpful than the message generated by VC++.

Comment: @James: bug is that VC++ doesn't complain about `Type::x` being non-type!

Comment: The code is ill-formed. Visual C++ reports a diagnostic. That's all that is required.  The diagnostic message may not be as helpful as it could be but that's a QOI issue, not a bug. g++ and Visual C++ both have many less than helpful diagnostic messages that are often misleading.

Comment: It doesn't have to. The code is invalid and it rejects it. The error message doesn't have to be pretty.

Comment: @James: Correct. Removed that part.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11, the using keyword can be used for type alias

```
struct Type
{
    using x = static int const;
};
```